# Get constraint constant by size class

Tags: ios, swift4, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to get the constraint constant of a size class programmatically.

This is the width constraint:

[image]

I added an outlet for the control using this constraint.  I access the constraint constant like this:

```
let constantValue = repeatIconWidth.constant
```

When I check the value in constantValue, it is always 30, regardless of which device I am running.  I have an iPad Pro and it is using the value of 40 for the width, but checking constant will gives me 30.

How can I access the value that is actually being used to set the width of the icon?

Comment: Where are you accessing the constant? `viewDidLoad`? Do it in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the constraint before updating it.
update the constraint and then get the value inside the **viewDidLayoutSubviews**